# Unable to uninstall the x64 TargetPlatform msi using 32-bit PowerShell

Tags: windows-installer, powershell-2.0

I have a msi with TargetPlatform x64 bit mode. I have also PowerShell 2.0 installed in my machine which is running in 32 bit mode. I have installed the msi using powershell script. Now when I try to uninstall the msi using powershell script as mentioned below I am getting an error:

Unable to find application TestSetup

```
function Uninstall-MSI([string]$name)
{
    $success = $false

    # Read installation information from the registry
    $registryLocation = Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"
    foreach ($registryItem in $registryLocation)
    {
        # If we get a match on the application name
        if ((Get-itemproperty $registryItem.PSPath).DisplayName -eq $name)
        {
            # Get the product code if possible
            $productCode = (Get-itemproperty $registryItem.PSPath).ProductCode

            # If a product code is available, uninstall using it
            if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($productCode) -eq $false)
            {
                Write-Host "Uninstalling $name, ProductCode:$code"              
                $args="/uninstall $code"

                [diagnostics.process]::start("msiexec", $args).WaitForExit()                
                $success = $true
            }
            # If there is no product code, try to read the uninstall string
            else
            {
                $uninstallString = (Get-itemproperty $registryItem.PSPath).UninstallString

                if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($uninstallString) -eq $false)
                {
                    # Grab the product key and create an argument string
                    $match = [RegEx]::Match($uninstallString, "{.*?}")
                    $args = "/x $($match.Value) /qn"

                    [diagnostics.process]::start("msiexec", $args).WaitForExit()
                    Write-Host $uninstallString                 
                    $success = $true
                }
                else { throw "Unable to uninstall $name" }
            }           
        }
    }

    if ($success -eq $false)
    { throw "Unable to find application $name" }
}

Uninstall-MSI "TestSetup"
```

I then updated the MSI to x86 bit mode and performed installation and then tried for uninstallation using the same powershell script as mentioned above. It worked for me without any issues.

Can anyone help me to resolve the above issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed the issue further and found that in my machine the Powershell Process is running in 32 bit mode whereas the msi is with TargetPlatform x64 bit mode. The Powershell Process running in 32 bit mode cannot read the registry entries for 64 bit mode applications. I tested the same in a web server where I have Powershell running in x64 bit mode and the msi with TargetPlatform x64 bit mode and it worked fine for me.